# youtube-v3-api "Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?

Tags: c#, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Hi I am working on an Web application that uploads a video to the users Youtube Channel. I used the code which is given in the google **Youtube API** guide.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine("YouTube Data API: Upload Video");
  Console.WriteLine("==============================");

  try
  {
    new UploadVideo().Run().Wait();
  }
  catch (AggregateException ex)
  {
    foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
    }
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
  Console.ReadKey();
}

private async Task Run()
{
  UserCredential credential;
  using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  {
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
        // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None
    );
  }

  var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
  {
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
  });

  var video = new Video();
  video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
  video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
  video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
  video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
  video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
  video.Status = new VideoStatus();
  video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"
  var filePath = @"REPLACE_ME.mp4"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.

  using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
  {
    var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");


    await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
  }
}
```

This code works fine when I run it in visual studio locally and the video gets uploaded to my Youtube channel. But the problem which I face is when I host the application in the IIS at a server machine it throws a Access Denied exception to the folder

> 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile'

I gave the permission to the folder and now it threw an different exception

> "Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A62196%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.upload" for authorization. See inner exception for details."

Comment: where is this code executed from? sadly, afaik, the google api for dotnet should only work on client side (no, not website) and need the user to login when it need to authenticate. when it ask for creds, it will instead launch a web browser -- not exactly what an API you want do. i suppose you ran it on a website instead of client (desktop) application.

Comment: The code is executed from the server. I have the client's ID and secret is there anyway to upload the video directly to the user's youtube channel ?

Comment: check on [the docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow), i havent tried myself. It still need the client to login from google first though..